# How does FFT work? Can't seem to the frequency spectrum for each frame in Rust

Tags: rust, fft, tauri

I am only getting 735 frequencies of audio data each 0.03 seconds.

I am trying to figure how how I can get the frequency spectrum in each frame. The code below only returns 735 of data each frame (because `samples_in_frame` is 735, that's how many samples in each frame), but I want the whole ~20,000hz for 0.03 seconds of samples. How would I go about doing this?

`path`: path to the wave file

`second_start`: start point to process in seconds, 0

`second_length`: how long to process in seconds, 10

`frame_rate`: how many frames in each second, 60

```rust
fn fft_this(mut buffer: Vec<Complex<f64>>, samples_in_frame: usize) -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut planner = FftPlanner::new();

    let fft = planner.plan_fft_forward(samples_in_frame);

    fft.process(&mut buffer[..]);

    let mut frame_data: Vec<f64> = Vec::with_capacity(samples_in_frame);

    for i in 0..samples_in_frame {
        frame_data.push(buffer[i].norm())
    }

    return frame_data;
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn analyze(
    path: &str,
    second_start: f64,
    second_length: f64,
    frame_rate: f64,
) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {
    let wave_file: Wave64 = Wave64::load(path).expect("Could not load wave.");

    let samples_start: f64 = second_start * wave_file.sample_rate();
    let samples_in_each_frame: usize = (wave_file.sample_rate() / frame_rate) as usize;

    let frames_in_length: usize = (second_length * frame_rate) as usize;

    let mut wave_buffer: Vec<Vec<f64>> = vec![];

    for frame_index in 0..frames_in_length {
        let mut frame_buffer: Vec<Complex<f64>> = vec![];

        for sample_index in 0..samples_in_each_frame {
            let buffer_index: usize = frame_index * sample_index + samples_start as usize;

            frame_buffer.push(Complex {
                re: wave_file.at(0, buffer_index),
                im: 0.0,
            });
        }

        let processed_frame: Vec<f64> = fft_this(frame_buffer, samples_in_each_frame);

        wave_buffer.push(processed_frame);
    }

    return wave_buffer;
}
```

Comment: 735/0.03s = 24.5kHz. So the highest frequency you can detect is 24.5kHz/2 = 12.25kHz. If you want to detect 20kHz frequencies, you need to sample at 40kHz. That's unrelated to Rust, or even FFTs. That's the fundamental nature of sampling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem

Comment: Maybe a post like this one would get you on the right track. It sounds like you're not familiar with how to interpret the output of an FFT (for example, a result covering 20kHz, even if you were sampling fast enough, isn't going to have 20,000 values). https://phip1611.de/blog/frequency-spectrum-analysis-with-fft-in-rust/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need more background information about FFTs in general.

If you have 735 data points, this data only consists of 735 orthogonal frequencies.

Lets assume those 735 points represent 1 second. Then:

- The first FFT value is the DC part, `0 Hz`, and the average of all values.
- The second one is `1 Hz`, the slowest contained frequency, meaning one full cycle during the sampling period.
- The next one is `2 Hz`, meaning two full cycles during the sampling period.
- ...
- `367 Hz`, meaning 367 full cycles
- `368 Hz`, meaning 368 full cycles. **IMPORTANT:** Due to aliasing (see "Sampling Theorem") this is identical to `-367 Hz`, meaning, `367 Hz` rotating in the opposite direction!
- `-366 Hz`
- `-365 Hz`
- ...
- `-1 Hz`

In total those are 735 frequencies. There isn't more information in the signal.

In your case, as your time period is not 1 second but 0.03 seconds, you need to multiply your frequencies by `1/0.03` = `33.33`. So you get:

- `0 Hz`
- `33.33 Hz`
- `66.66 Hz`
- ...
- `12200 Hz`
- `12233.33 Hz`
- `-12233.33 Hz`
- `-12200 Hz`
- ...
- `-66.66 Hz`
- `-33.33 Hz`

There simply isn't more information in your samples.

**Additional important info:**

For the FFT, it looks like the signal you give to it is repeating endlessly. So if your 735 samples aren't actually repeating (which I guess they aren't), you need to apply a window function to reduce the artifacts you get from odd frequencies. For example, a clean `1.5 Hz` signal in the 1 second case will give you some weird overtones because applying no window function is equivalent to applying a rectangular window function, which has horrible overtones. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Rectangular_window).

For visual learners, I can strongly recommend the [videos of 3Blue1Brown about the fourier transform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY).